# DevExpress Filter Editor : DropdownList

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, devexpress

When constructing filter in [Filter Editor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2470), can i provide list of possible values ?

**Example :**

[image]

Can I have here ComboBox with possible values instead of TextEdit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You should handle the FilterEditorCreated event of the GridView as shown below:

```
private void gridView1_FilterEditorCreated(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FilterControlEventArgs e) {
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemComboBox combo = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemComboBox();
    combo.Items.Add("Item 1");
    combo.Items.Add("Item 2");
    e.FilterControl.FilterColumns["ProductName"].SetColumnEditor(combo);
}
```

Comment: i cant use this, iam using filter control instead of right click of  filter editor on gridview.